# VUE JS appends the current site url in a dynamic binding for href . How to only bind the string and not append in the current URL?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to dynamically bind URLS which I am getting from json data in a HTTP Response.
By doing this :

```
<a :href="item['attachment'] " ><p>VIEW FILE</p></a>
```

I am getting value for href is:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/127.0.0.1:8000/media/f90efb3b-741b-49fd-b07f-e5ecbaa76ba6/1600894650_916033.pdf
```

As you can see that I am getting the url appended like this.

**What I want to do is to assign value of href to:**

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/f90efb3b-741b-49fd-b07f-e5ecbaa76ba6/1600894650_916033.pdf
```

Comment: How exactly does the url returned from xhr look like?

Comment: It looks like this 127.0.0.1:8000/media/f90efb3b-741b-49fd-b07f-e5ecbaa76ba6/1600894650_916033.pdf